# Save and New functionality in Custom Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need a help in writing logic for save and new functionality in my custom lightning component which is showing in a modal.On the click of this button the form should again show in this modal and record should also get created.I am not finding any material/documentation for this.

Comment: Kindly update your question and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am able to figure it out.Sorry for trouble.

Comment: Community would be able to help you better if you add code to the question.